# d3 hierarchy ability to average children node values

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, ecmascript-6

I have a d3 visualization that has a JSON object similar to the following where I would like to average up the value of `score` on the lowest nodes and dynamically add that average to the parent node above...and so on.  It doesn't look like d3 has an easy method to do this.  What I'd like is to have the final JSON output look like the second example.

```
 {
  "name": "A1",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "B1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "B1-C1",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "B1-C1-D1",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D1-E1",
                  "value": 30,
                  "score": 0.8
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D1-E2",
                  "value": 35,
                  "score": 0.5
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "B1-C1-D2",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D2-E1",
                  "value": 31,
                  "score": 0.4
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D2-E2",
                  "value": 23,
                  "score": 0.7
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'd like the final JSON object to look like:

```
{
  "name": "A1",
  "scoreAvg": 0.625,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "B1",
      "scoreAvg": 0.625,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "B1-C1",
          "scoreAvg": 0.625,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "B1-C1-D1",
              "scoreAvg": 0.7,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D1-E1",
                  "value": 30,
                  "score": 0.8
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D1-E2",
                  "value": 35,
                  "score": 0.6
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "B1-C1-D2",
              "scoreAvg": 0.55,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D2-E1",
                  "value": 31,
                  "score": 0.4
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D2-E2",
                  "value": 23,
                  "score": 0.7
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive function:

```js
const obj = {
  "name": "A1",
  "children": [{
    "name": "B1",
    "children": [{
      "name": "B1-C1",
      "children": [{
          "name": "B1-C1-D1",
          "children": [{
              "name": "B1-C1-D1-E1",
              "value": 30,
              "score": 0.8
            },
            {
              "name": "B1-C1-D1-E2",
              "value": 35,
              "score": 0.5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "B1-C1-D2",
          "children": [{
              "name": "B1-C1-D2-E1",
              "value": 31,
              "score": 0.4
            },
            {
              "name": "B1-C1-D2-E2",
              "value": 23,
              "score": 0.7
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  }]
}

function getWithAverageScore(objToRecurse) {
  // If I have a score I am already done
 if (objToRecurse.score) {
  return objToRecurse;
 }
  // Otherwise, I get my children with their average score
 const children = objToRecurse.children.map(getWithAverageScore);

 return {
  ...objToRecurse,
  children,
    // And I set my scoreAvg to their average (score or scoreAvg)
  scoreAvg: children.reduce((total, { score, scoreAvg }) => total + (score || scoreAvg), 0) / children.length
 };
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getWithAverageScore(obj), null, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let o = {
  "name": "A1",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "B1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "B1-C1",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "B1-C1-D1",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D1-E1",
                  "value": 30,
                  "score": 0.8
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D1-E2",
                  "value": 35,
                  "score": 0.5
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "B1-C1-D2",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D2-E1",
                  "value": 31,
                  "score": 0.4
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D2-E2",
                  "value": 23,
                  "score": 0.7
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};


function avgUp(object){
  object.avgScore = 0;
if(object.children){
  for(child of object.children){
    object.avgScore += avgUp(child);
   }
object.avgScore =  object.avgScore /Math.max(1,object.children.length);
   return object.avgScore;
}else{
return object.score;
}
}

avgUp(o);

console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
```